# How to accept a variable numer of inputs?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a `for` loop with 5 iterations.
Each time through the loop, I need to input either *string int int* or *string int int int*.
That is, in each iteration, the program asks for either a combination of a string and 2 integers or a string and 3 integers. 
If I write `cin >> (string) s >> (int) a >> (int) b >> (int) c;` my program will stop as soon as I write a string and only 2 integers. Is there any way I can change this part of my program?

Example input:

```
sum 2 3
sub 5 3 
sum 1 5 6
sum 2 5 6
sub 1 7
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. This instructions are unclear. Can you please have a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask We need to know also what you tried. Thanks.

Comment: Don't judge him, he is just trying to help. I edited my post.

Comment: So there still remains a lot of unanswered questions left after your recent edit. Your question title is asking how to choose between two conditions, I assume the result of the condition is do you read 2, or 3 ints after the string. That makes sense. What you don't make clear is, are you reading an input file? Is the `sum 2 3` from the file? Are you taking these as input from the user? Is it all one line, separate lines? Your example shows you trying to read 3 ints, you say it stops after reading 2 -- so where is that code that does that? Can we see it? We need more information to help out.

Comment: Also you fail to make clear what is suppose to determine if you read 2 or 3 ints? What are the two conditions? Can you enter more than three ints? Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: I've tried to clean up the writing in your question. If I've misunderstood something and inadvertently changed your meaning, feel free to revert that change. Also, it might help if you posted your current attempt at writing your loop.

Answer (score 4):

1. Read the input line by line.
2. Process each line using a [`std::istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) to produce the desired output.

---

```
std::string line;
while ( getline(std::cin, line) )
{
    std::istringstring str(line)

    std::string token;
    if ( str >> token )
    {
        std::cout << "string ";
    }

    int n;
    while ( str >> n )
    {
        std::cout << "int ";
    }
}
```

Comment: So how does this solve the problem? I'm not even sure how you got enough information to try and provide an answer this detailed.

Comment: This approach allows the user to enter as many ints as they want on each line. The program will read a whole line in one go, and then read as many `int`s are actually on that line, then repeat for each subsequent line. This is exactly the same approach I would have taken.

Comment: If we start making assumptions about the question asked, I would agree this solves the problem. Except the question was, "How do I decide to switch from reading 2 to 3 ints" in a loop. It also stated the loop iterates 5 times only, it's just wholly unclear whether the input is in a file to be read, put in by a user as a single line, done individually on their own lines. The code he given is literally a line-by-line approach and your solution reads from a single line -- already we're at two entirely different solutions to different problems. I just don't think we have the information to answer.